# Android kernel error: 'struct kernel_stat' has no member named 'cpustat' and error: 'struct request' has no member named 'elevator_private'

Tags: android, c++, c, struct, linux-kernel

I'm compiling kernel kernel for S5 mini LTE and I'm receiving these errors:

1.

```
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_pegasusq.c: In function 'get_cpu_idle_time_jiffy':
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_pegasusq.c:420: error: 'struct kernel_stat' has no member named 'cpustat'
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_pegasusq.c:420: error: 'struct kernel_stat' has no member named 'cpustat'
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_pegasusq.c:423: error: 'struct kernel_stat' has no member named 'cpustat'
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_pegasusq.c:424: error: 'struct kernel_stat' has no member named 'cpustat'
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_pegasusq.c:425: error: 'struct kernel_stat' has no member named 'cpustat'
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_pegasusq.c:426: error: 'struct kernel_stat' has no member named 'cpustat'
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_pegasusq.c: In function 'store_ignore_nice_load':
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_pegasusq.c:661: error: 'struct kernel_stat' has no member named 'cpustat'
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_pegasusq.c: In function 'dbs_check_cpu':
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_pegasusq.c:1125: error: 'struct kernel_stat' has no member named 'cpustat'
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_pegasusq.c:1134: error: 'struct kernel_stat' has no member named 'cpustat'
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_pegasusq.c: In function 'cpufreq_governor_dbs':
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_pegasusq.c:1380: error: 'struct kernel_stat' has no member named 'cpustat'
make[2]: *** [drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_pegasusq.o] Błąd 1
make[2]: *** Oczekiwanie na niezakończone zadania....
CC kernel/audit_watch.o
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_pegasusqplus.c: In function 'get_cpu_idle_time_jiffy':
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_pegasusqplus.c:484: error: 'struct kernel_stat' has no member named 'cpustat'
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_pegasusqplus.c:484: error: 'struct kernel_stat' has no member named 'cpustat'
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_pegasusqplus.c:487: error: 'struct kernel_stat' has no member named 'cpustat'
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_pegasusqplus.c:488: error: 'struct kernel_stat' has no member named 'cpustat'
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_pegasusqplus.c:489: error: 'struct kernel_stat' has no member named 'cpustat'
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_pegasusqplus.c:490: error: 'struct kernel_stat' has no member named 'cpustat'
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_pegasusqplus.c: In function 'store_ignore_nice_load':
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_pegasusqplus.c:720: error: 'struct kernel_stat' has no member named 'cpustat'
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_pegasusqplus.c: In function 'dbs_check_cpu':
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_pegasusqplus.c:1465: error: 'struct kernel_stat' has no member named 'cpustat'
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_pegasusqplus.c:1474: error: 'struct kernel_stat' has no member named 'cpustat'
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_pegasusqplus.c: In function 'cpufreq_governor_dbs':
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_pegasusqplus.c:1934: error: 'struct kernel_stat' has no member named 'cpustat'
make[2]: *** [drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_pegasusqplus.o] Błąd 1
make[1]: *** [drivers/cpufreq] Błąd 2
make: *** [drivers] Błąd 2
```

2.

```
block/row-iosched.c: In function 'row_add_request':
block/row-iosched.c:278: error: 'struct request' has no member named 'elevator_private'
block/row-iosched.c: In function 'row_reinsert_req':
block/row-iosched.c:325: error: 'struct request' has no member named 'elevator_private'
block/row-iosched.c: In function 'row_remove_request':
block/row-iosched.c:377: error: 'struct request' has no member named 'elevator_private'
block/row-iosched.c: In function 'row_merged_requests':
block/row-iosched.c:605: error: 'struct request' has no member named 'elevator_private'
block/row-iosched.c: In function 'row_set_request':
block/row-iosched.c:650: error: 'struct request' has no member named 'elevator_private'
make[1]: *** [block/row-iosched.o] Błąd 1
make: *** [block] Błąd 2
make: *** Oczekiwanie na niezakończone zadania....
```

I tried to fix second error and I received this:

```
block/elevator.c: In function 'elv_set_request':
block/elevator.c:702: error: 'struct request' has no member named 'elevator_private'
make[1]: *** [block/elevator.o] Błąd 1
make: *** [block] Błąd 2
make: *** Oczekiwanie na niezakończone zadania....
```

From [this repo](https://github.com/KK2345/android_kernel_samsung_kminilte).

I'm a noob. I'm starting my adventure with kernel development. Thanks for your help.

P.S. I fixed the second error by adding

```
rq->elevator_private[0] = NULL;
```

in

```
int elv_set_request(struct request_queue *q, struct request *rq, gfp_t gfp_mask)
```

in block/elevator.c

Comment: How did you try to fix the second error?

Comment: I added this line
    
`rq->elevator_private[0] = NULL;`

in
    
`int elv_set_request(struct request_queue *q, struct request *rq, gfp_t gfp_mask)`

in file `block/elevator.c`